# How to mirror the contraints rotation and limit rotation?

Tags: rigging

Hi I would like to mirror the left hand's bones to the right hand's bones, I have constrained some of them and limit their rotation in one hand (I think I put the x-mirror too late, very late ) , however it seems x-mirror does not work, or not update ...so I have one hand with the constraint and the other have not any contraints. How can I mirror the constraint (location and rotacion ) from one hand to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want it will be easier to use python. I wrote a script that copies constraint from bones with ".L" to corresponding bones with ".R"

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
arm = bpy.data.objects["Armature"]
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
arm.select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = arm
bpy.ops.object.posemode_toggle()
bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='SELECT')
all_bones = bpy.context.selected_pose_bones
for bone in all_bones:
    bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    if ".L" in bone.name:
        boneL = arm.data.bones[bone.name]
        boneR = arm.data.bones[bone.name.replace('.L','.R')]
        boneR.select = True
        boneL.select = True
        arm.data.bones.active = boneL
        bpy.ops.object.constraints_copy()
        bpy.ops.pose.constraints_copy()
        for con in arm.pose.bones[boneR.name].constraints:
           con.subtarget = con.subtarget.replace('.L','.R')
```

Another way to do it without Python is to use the Copy Constraint, which involves manual work to be done, you select an object then add a Copy Constraint, then select which other object you want to copy the property from (location, rotation). So no need for paste constraint.

Comment: another way? thanks by the way.

Comment: @ReifusRufus answer updated. The good thing about the python way is that it's automatic, the other way involved doing everything manually.

Comment: I prefer manual for the rigging process, should I paste that code in the editor script? I do not a big fan of python . but I think I should paste the code and see what happened in an extra windows for the editor?

Comment: @ReifusRufus It's up to you. To run the code, open a text editor, new, then paste the code and replace "Armature" with the name of your armature e.g "My_Armature" then run the script. This script will copy all constraints of bones ending with .L to bones with same name but .R

Comment: I converter my armature the "metarig" all the constraints that I need use the metarig as a target. so I need to put "metarig" instead  ".armature"

Comment: @ReifusRufus You can provide a screenshot of your outliner and I'll tell you what to replace.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/zI6qo see it, I ve deleted the riggify addon, that's why in the outliner it said armature.006...damn I hate the addon xD , so Metarig ->pose->armature.006.> (many objects, there a lot of lowpoly mesh, LP_lowerPants,Lp_UpperJacket,etc) it is a different workflow, differentes UV's for every objects.

Comment: @ReifusRufus an easier way may be is to rename both Armature.006 and metarig to MyArmature, in this case you won't have to edit the script

Comment: Ok I would consider your advice,

Comment: @ReifusRufus you can send me a link of your .blend file and I'll let you know.